# Sass Intellij File Watcher Output path Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, file-watcher

I am trying to compile a .scss file in sass directory to a sibling css directory. However, I am not able to. I dint find enough documentation on the file watcher plugin as well. 
Currently, it is compiling into the sass directory. And I need to compile into css directory.
I am able to compile it manually using

```
sass --watch sass/file.scss:css/file.css
```

How do I do it using Intellij File Watcher plugin?

I tried using the macros but I dont think I understand macros much, because I either get directory not found or .scss file not found. I am aware that I have to change the argument input in some way, but

```
--watch sass/file.scss:css/file.scss
```

dint work.
Pl help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you may have figured this out by now. But this may be helpful for future searches.

You don't need to add `sass --watch` to the arguments because that happens implicitly via the Intellij watcher.

But lets say you have a directory structure like so...

```
-C
 -path
   -to
     -css
       styles.css
       -sass
          styles.scss
```

You would do something like this in *Arguments*:

```
--no-cache --update C:\path\to\css\sass:C:\path\to\css
```

And then set your working directory to *C:\path\to\css\sass*

**Example:**

[image]